# Set checkbox for selected QTreeview Items

Tags: c++, qt

How do i set the checkbox for the selected Treeview items in my QTreeview C++ project?

My goal is to iterate over the selected Treeview items and set their checkbox state to true or false. I'll be doing this through a righclick menu. I just don't know how to collect the selected items.

I wrote a function that loops through all the items and sets the checkboxes to true or false, but I'm struggling to figure out how to set only the selected items.

```
void ShotsEditor::checkAll()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < d->sourceModel->rowCount(); i++){
        QStandardItem* item = d->sourceModel->item(i);
        if (item->isCheckable())
        {
            item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        else{
            if (item->hasChildren())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < item->rowCount(); j++){
                     QStandardItem* item1 = item->child(j);
                     if (item1->isCheckable())
                     {
                         item1->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck...

```
void ShotsEditor::checkSelected()
{
    QModelIndexList selected = d->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    qDebug() << "selected indexes" << selected;
    foreach (QModelIndex index, selected)
    {
        if (index.column()==0)
        {
            int row = index.row();
            qDebug() << "row" << row;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is how i would do it in pyside. I don't know how to do it in c++

```
  def set_checked(self):
        indexes = self.treeview.selectedIndexes()

        for i in indexes:
            model = i.model()
            item = i.model().itemFromIndex(i)
            print i, model, item

            if item.isSelectable():
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected ?, you could explain me please.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated the question with more info

Comment: @JokerMartini How you select them?

Comment: I'm selecting them through the UI by clicking on them.

Comment: Okay, I understand :P

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to get the items selected is overwriting the [`selectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionChanged) slot, it returns the selected and deselected items, then we get the items through the indexes and check them.

```
class TreeView : public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected slots:
    void selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected){
        Q_UNUSED(deselected)
        const auto *m = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel *>(model());
        if(m){
            for(const auto index: selected.indexes()){
                m->itemFromIndex(index)->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
            }
        }
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TreeView w;
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        QStandardItem *parent =new  QStandardItem(QString("Family %1").arg(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            QStandardItem *child = new QStandardItem(QString("item %1").arg(j));
            parent->appendRow(child);
        }
        model->appendRow(parent);
    }

    w.setModel(model);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The complete example you find in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/de685e311c1ad18dad40b1bef12e1aea)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this same problem:

```
QModelIndexList selected = d->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
qDebug() << "selected" << selected;
foreach (QModelIndex index, selected)
{
    QStandardItem* item = d->sourceModel->itemFromIndex(index);
    qDebug() << "item" << item;
    if (item->isSelectable() && item->isCheckable())
    {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    }
}
```